# Analyzing .txt file consisting of tweets line by line

Tags: string, matlab, file-io

how would I use multiple fgetl operations to have Matlab read my 30 line of text .txt file. I cannot just put all the lines into one variable because I need to analyze information within the file using Matlab. The information I need to examine are things like how many lines are in the file as well as questions regarding how many certain letters, or symbols are in each line.

I have started out with this code so far

```
clear all
close all
clc
%% Questions Two
% part a
fid = fopen('twitter_data.txt');
twitter = fread(fid,inf,'*char')';
fclose(fid);
```

Just noticed the above doesnt work though cause i need it line by line, not all the character in one columns row vector

Comment: Related:  http://stackoverflow.com/q/13755048/931379
Generally you should edit the original question if needed rather than start a new question.  Editing a question brings it back to the front, and in the end we end up with one good question / answer, rather than a series of similar, less good questions.

Answer (score 2):

You want to use [`fgetl`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fgetl.html). In addition, you could find patterns with [`strfind`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strfind.html).

```
fid = fopen('twitter_data.txt');
twitter = fgetl(fid);
while ischar(twitter)
   %Process twitter here
   fprintf('Line contains %i # symbols',length(strfind(twitter,'#')));

   %get next line
   twitter = fgetl(fid);
end
fclose(fid);
```

Comment: i get the following error Error using fgetl
Too many input arguments.

Error in TwitterProject (line 7)
twitter = fgetl(fid,inf,'*char')';

Comment: Sorry about that... That's what I get for copy/pasting and not checking everything. It should work now.

Comment: okay thank you it works now, but I am still confused with the variables i get. how would I lets say find out how many of the symbol '#' are in my file or on a specific line.

Comment: I get the variables twitter = -1, fid = 20

Comment: Well, twitter's last value will be -1 (End of File). But if you check it in the while loop, it will have some value. As far as what else you might want to do, that could be a large question indeed... But I'll at least let you in on one way to find the number of '#' characters in the string.